# Repleace type of element to the slug

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a table with type (boolean field). But I want to use slug name in order to display articles with a specyfic type. This is more complicated becouse website has a 2 language version. So I created model and migration:

```
Schema::create('slugsites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id(); 
            $table->string('lang');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('translate');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

In controller I set lang and slug and I get translate (type).

```
$type = Slugsite::where('language', Config::get('app.locale'))->where('slug', $type)->first();
```

It works correctly but I have a problem with build links to this route. I don't know how I can call back slug of my element's type in simple way.

Comment: Code of the element you want to use this slug approach and how the relationship is setup?`

Comment: On this moment I didn't make any relationship between this two models becouse I don't have idea how can I do that.

Comment: Then show the model and its fields :)

Comment: Models is empty becouse all records is create by seeder (I think about Slugsite). I know that propably I need create relationship in order to solve my problem but at this moment I don't have that, I showed fields in my first post.

Comment: Then i think i misunderstand the question, "I don't know how I can call back slug of my element's type in simple way. " can you explain what you mean by this

Comment: OK. Let assume that slug is 'my-fovourite-food' or 'moje-ulubione-jedzenie' (if checked language is polish) but in elements of type is 1 (type field is int). So I use Slugsites in order to repleace number to slug. It's simple. But I want to build a link and in this link must be found a slug. How can I do that?